# How to use simulateTransaction without having valid signatures

Tags: transactions, signature, simulate

in my program i have a function which mutates some accounts and calculate a value A, i was retrieving this value by parsing the logs, but the issue is on the UI side it requires a signature from the user ,is there a way to simulate tx without valid signatures ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `"sigVerify":false` with the [`simulateTransaction` options](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#simulatetransaction),

Comment: Sadly though in the current web3 library this option isn't exposed

Comment: Sounds like a great opportunity to contribute to the repo!

Comment: lol, isn't there already someone from solana working on a new web3 library

Comment: all i've seen is a proposal.  getting a two-liner in for this option in the meantime would likely still be valuable

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/master/src/connection.ts#L4429), the signatures verification should automatically be skipped if no signers are provided. Maybe a wallet is passed as a signer automatically in your code, triggering the check?

Comment: i guess i need to clear this up here, the actual progrma ix does require some signers but i was hoping if there was a way to skip actual signatures by those users in a bid to simulateTx without having it popup approve repeatedly on the phantom UI

Comment: Hmm. Not sure I understand the distinction. Either the signatures are verified and you need to provide the ones required, or they are not like in the case of a simulation and it does not matter what sigs the ix requires outside of simulation?

Comment: now that i think of it i believe it is not possible, but what i wanted to do was , simulate an arbitary tx even in the case if required signatures which i could not give , just for the sake of simulation, but i believe this kind of tx will fail validation and hence is not possible,